# Shopify embeded rails app example is pending on registering in argus.shopify.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I cloned the [Shopify embeded app example](https://github.com/Shopify/embedded-app-example) and set my API key and secret and then authorized the app through Shopify. Now that I want to open the app in the admin panel (supposed to render index method of home controller) it shows nothing since the embedded app is trying to get a page with path: 
 `wss://argus.shopify.com/820222/register?token=foo&screen_sharing_support=true&user_name=Pooya%20M&guid=bar`

This request is pending and does not finish.

What is wrong here and how can I fix this?

Comment: did you check your callbacks urls? Did you make sure you checked the 'embedded app' radio button? Btw, do you know this seaff.microapps.com

Comment: are you aware you're hitting Shopify 'global' site rather than a Shopify store? Try argus.myshopify.com

Comment: btw, just for curiosity, why are you using web socets protocol?

Comment: @alexandresaiz you mean callbacks url for authentication? yes and I'm using seaff but it was not related to this issue since in this question, I was using a clone of shopify project which had not used seaff.

Comment: why do you use: /argus.shopify.com ? just for curiosity, and why do you use: wss:// also for curiosity :-)

Comment: @alexandresaiz I'm not using this url and they do not exist in the project. I think these come from shopify. Anyway, I tried to reproduce the error but apparently it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. The problem of showing nothing was because of rendering an HTTP page from an HTTPS one (localhost is without SSL by default) . 
Lgs were disabled in my inspector. I enabled error logs in my inspector, and I resolved the errors (one of them was this insecure rendering).

P.S: You can add SSL to localhost or disable the protection of your browser.